# select data from two tables using simple sql query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

If I have following query

```
if not exists(select * from DeliveryTemplate where TemplateId=2)
                begin                                       
                    select usersCode, 1,2,'User {UsersCode}',' hello {Username},', null 
                    from User
                end
```

how can I extend this query in order to select one more column `DeliveryCode` from `DeliveryTemplate` table?

Comment: Does User and DeliveryTemplate has a relationship?

Comment: yes, DeliveryTemplate has UserId column.

Comment: check the below answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to use `JOIN` something like:

```
if not exists(select * from DeliveryTemplate where TemplateId=2)
                begin 
                   select u.usersCode, 1,2,'User {UsersCode}',' hello {Username},', null, dt.DeliveryCode 
                   from User u
                   left join DeliveryTemplate dt on u.Id = dt.UserId
                end
```

Comment: you need add something on the where to reproduce the not exists

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int
declare @DeliveryCode nvarchar(100)
select @count = count(*), 
       @DeliveryCode = DeliveryCode 
       from DeliveryTemplate 
       where TemplateId=2

if @count = 0 
begin                                       
 select usersCode, 
        1, 
        2,
        'User {UsersCode}', 
        'hello {Username},',
        null,
       @DeliveryCode AS 'DeliveryCode'
       from User
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done as follows with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT usersCode, 1,2,'User {UsersCode}',' hello {Username},', null, DeliveryCode
FROM User 
INNER JOIN DeliveryTemplate ON User.ID=DeliveryTemplate.UserId 
WHERE TemplateId=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists(select * from DeliveryTemplate where TemplateId=2)
            begin                                       
              select usersCode, 1,2,'User {UsersCode}',' hello {Username},', null, DeliveryCode
              from User AS u
              INNER JOIN DeliveryTemplate AS d
              ON u.ID = d.UserID
            end
```